# How do i restrict the users of other domain apart from **abc.com**

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I have to build a custom module in which i have added a custom fields on to the customer registration page a fields like alternate mail id,mobile number & etc which is successfully getting saved in my database & here i have to implement a one more feature that is

on registration page when user enters his email id that should check for the domain name.

Ex: my domain name is **abc** & the users mail address will be **user@abc.com**

& the users of **"abc.com"** should only has to get register into my online store 
How do i restrict the users of other domain apart from **abc.com**

Please help me in doing this.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [magento-customer Registration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936399/magento-customer-registration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression for this. Just use the below function:

```
function checkEmail($email) {
  if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@abc.com$/",$email)){

    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

***Code Edited***

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateEmail(elementValue){  
       var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@abc.com$/;  
       return emailPattern.test(elementValue);  
     }  

    function checkForm(){
        var emailId = document.getElementById('email_address').value;
        if(! validateEmail(emailId)) {
            alert("Email id is not valid");
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="input-box"style="width: 550px;"> 
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" /> 

    <input type="submit" value="Click here" onclick="checkForm()" />(There will be be an submit button put the onclick event in it)

</div>
```

Comment: can the same thing be done using javascript if so please provide me a piece of code for it which helps me alot.......

Comment: Yes you can put this in your register.phtml or if you have many js functions like this, then you can put them in your js file and put the path of that js file in your xml file.

Comment: ok can you tell me were i should insert the in this div <div class="input-box"style="width: 550px;">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />    
</div>

Comment: superb script, i tested it & its working nicely instead of inserting a new button & when i click that button its working but when i click submit directly its not working how can i do this with my regular  submit button please help.....

Comment: No need to insert a new button. use this code :- onclick="checkForm()" from above button to your regular submit button.

Comment: i used onBlur event for the input field instead of the onClick event for the submit button....